# Plotting a frequency distribution with count and score (precision) for the frequenct

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot, ggplot2

I have a dataset of a million documents. I took the frequency distribution of the documents based on the number of words in it. I also have the precision results for each document. Now I want to show the average precision per frequency. How do I plot this? What kind of diagram can incorporate boht the frequncy and the precision for each count

My dataset sample

`name, number of words,precision
doc1, 3, 0.3
dco2,4,0.2
doc3,3,0.1
doc4,3,0.2
doc5,5,0.5`

Now what I need to plot is

`freq., count, mean prec.
3, 3,0.2
4,1,0.2
5,1,0.5`

Comment: How are your two data sets related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you prefer on the x-axis, but you could use freq. and count as x/y values. To also indicate the mean value, you may use `geom_count` to vary dot size depending on the mean value.

This is a very basic example, but it should give you an idea where you could go:

```
mydat <- data.frame(freq = c(3, 4, 5), count = c(3, 1, 1), mean.prc = c(.2, .2, .5))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = count, y = freq, size = mean.prc)) + geom_count()
```

[image]

You could of course switch your variables if you want `count` as dot size and `mean.prc` on any axis etc.

**Edit:**
To adjust the geom-size, you could tweak the scale and start with a zero as lower limit for dot-size proportion, e.g.:

```
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = count, y = freq, size = mean.prc)) + geom_count() +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0,.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Does ggplot let you make the size representation proportional? It seems harmful that the 0.3 dot is about 100x the size of the 0.2 dot.

Comment: I think with `scale_size*` you can define the size-range of geoms, e.g. `scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0,.5))`